# resolve error : "commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches"?

Tags: github, git-stash

I was on **master branch** which had following files in staging area :

```
modified:   app/assets/stylesheets/login.css
    modified:   app/controllers/application_controller.rb
    modified:   app/controllers/users_controller.rb
    modified:   app/views/users/forgot.html.erb
    modified:   app/views/users/new.html.erb
    new file:   app/views/users/new_password.html.erb
    modified:   config/routes.rb
```

As I wished to pull the latest commits, I stashed these files using

> "git stash"

, did a

> "git pull"

. Then I moved to my local branch **"password_change"** and did a

> "git stash pop".

Now i have above mentioned files in my local branch.
When i tried going back to master branch, it gave the following error :

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
    app/controllers/application_controller.rb
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
```

Aborting

I wish to keep these files only in my local branch i.e. "password_change" and move to master branch. How should I overcome the error? Please help me as I am new to github.

Comment: Well, commit them, as the error message says.

Comment: probably you added your application_controller.rb to gitignore locally. You can try `git update-index --no-assume-unchanged app/controllers/application_controller.rb` and try to commit it again.